# What does Carp::carp do in Perl?

Tags: perl, carp

Can anyone please explain me about `carp` subroutine with sample Perl code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the [`perldoc` for Carp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Carp).

`carp` is a alternative for Perl's `warn` function that uses stack trace information to show you where you called a function that issued a warning. This can be more helpful than `warn`'s behavior of telling you where the warning occurred.

An example:

This program:

```
1: sub square_root {
2:  my $arg = shift;
3:  if ($arg < 0) {
4:    warn "Can't take square root of a negative number";
5:  } else {
6:    return sqrt($arg);
7:  }
8: }
9: print square_root(-4);
```

tells you:

```
Can't take square root of a negative number at carpdemo.pl line 4.
```

But if we change `warn` to `carp`:

```
1: use Carp;
2: sub square_root {
3:  my $arg = shift;
4:  if ($arg < 0) {
5:    carp "Can't take square root of a negative number";
6:  } else {
7:    return sqrt($arg);
8:  }
9: }
10: print square_root(-4);
```

it tells you:

```
Can't take square root of a negative number at carpdemo.pl line 4
        main::square_root(-4) called at carpdemo.pl line 10
```

The extra line of information is helpful in tracking down places where you might be using a function or module incorrectly.

Comment: Stack trace: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace -- the list of functions that you are currently inside of

Comment: From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/carp :  **Carp** : *to find fault or complain querulously or unreasonably; be niggling in criticizing; cavil: to carp at minor errors.*

Answer (score 3):

http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html